# .cordova folder not creating on App Folder

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

Im learning to code in HTML5, I downloaded and installed Node.js, PhoneGap and cordova. Im trying to create a "Test" app and When I run the command:

c:\phonegapApps>phonegap create Test

It just creates the followiong folders:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOAAe.jpg)

"hooks","platforms","plugins","www" folders and config file.

But does not create the ".cordova" Folder which I need to continue with my course. Please Help Me!

Comment: The .cordova folder is not in your project folder, it is on that place where you installed cordova. Maybe in the root of your user account.

Comment: why do you need the .cordova folder?

Comment: Because I need the config.json file. But I've Watched somany courses and this folder is created automatically.